# how to send double value through bundle

Tags: java, android, eclipse

String is working fine, what about double ?

Here is my code

```
ImageView protect_me_btn=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.protect_me_btn);
protect_me_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pbupdate.setVisibility(4);
        String lat= Double.toString(latitude);
        Intent inte=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),set_alaram.class);
        Bundle lati=new Bundle();
        lati.putString("first",lat);
        inte.putExtras(lati);
        startActivity(inte);                    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send Double value using Bundle as to set_alaram Activity:

```
protect_me_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pbupdate.setVisibility(4);
            String lat= Double.toString(latitude);
            Intent inte=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), set_alaram.class);
            Bundle lati=new Bundle();
            lati.putString("first",lat);
            lati.putDouble("lat", latitude); //<< send double using putDouble
            inte.putExtras(lati);
            startActivity(inte);                    
        }
    });
```

and in `set_alaram` Activity get Double value from Bundle as

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

Double lat = bundle.getDouble("lat");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the double value in bundle in this way.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, DestinationActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putDouble("key", yourDoubleValue);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
```

In your another activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
double passedDoubleValue = bundle.getDouble("key");
```

Hope this helps.